# WARNING: Your version of git is 1.9.3. has serious security vulnerabilities

Tags: macos, git, security, heroku, homebrew

I received a warning regarding serious security vulnerability of git 1.9.3 during deploy to Heroku

I tried to update git via homebrew but found that git was not originally installed via homebrew

Then I installed it via homebrew

```
brew update
brew install git

==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/git-2.2.1.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring git-2.2.1.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
/usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

The "contrib" directory has been installed to:
/usr/local/share/git-core/contrib

Bash completion has been installed to:
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.2.1: 1356 files, 31M
```

After that when I checked git version it remained the same

```
⇒  git --version   
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

It seems to me **homebrew** installed **git** in folder **/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.2.1**

And finally my question:
what should I do to start using **homebrew git** instead of the original **git**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
⇒  which git
/usr/bin/git

⇒  git --version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

You need to rename original **git** at **/usr/bin/git**, e.g.

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-original
```

Now check location and version again

```
⇒  which git
/usr/local/bin/git

⇒  git --version
git version 2.2.1
```

Add a symlink for backward compatibility (in case your IDE uses direct location to git)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: Thank @Jubobs, but then I need to change the path to git in my IDE anyway

Comment: mv: rename /usr/bin/git to /usr/bin/git-original: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 6):

Like Jubobs commented, you can simply add it to your path like so:

> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Just change *~/.bash_profile* to whatever bash profile file you're using.

Comment: Thank you @mrstif, but it will not solve the issue with updating the new path to git in my IDE (RubyMine)

Comment: Of course @SergeSeletskyy, for hardcoded references to the git folder you either change it directly using your solution or simply edit the software's settings...

Comment: This worked for me, but could you explain why this solved my problem?

Comment: @katzkode It's basically because the system's PATH variable defines which executables are found directly in your terminal. The command I provided simply prepends the new Git installation folder to that variable, hence when you type 'git' in the terminal, the system will look for that command in the folders specified in the PATH variable starting from the first one. Since the new installation one is first, it will pick that one instead of the system's. More info on [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)